# error: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, angular7

I am working in a angular project and using plugin in my project and getting this error:
error: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated. I imported the package @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment.

.html file -

```
<ckeditor #editor [editor]="editor" [config]="config"></ckeditor>
```

and .ts file

```
    import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
    import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
     export class WelcomePageSettingComponent implements OnInit {  
      public editor = ClassicEditor;  
      public config = {
        plugins: [Alignment],
        toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', '|', 'alignment']   };   constructor() { 
       }
       constructor() { }
       ngOnInit() {  }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used ckeditor5-editor-classic instead of ckeditor5-build-classic and getting another error: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null.
 .html file

`<ckeditor [editor]="editor"></ckeditor>`
.ts file

```
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
 import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor";
 export class WelcomePageSettingComponent implements OnInit {
   public editor = ClassicEditor;
   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit() {
     ClassicEditor
     .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
        plugins: [Alignment],
        toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', '|', 'italic', '|', 'mediaEmbed', '|',  
        'alignment']
      })
      .then()
      .catch();
  }
}
```